# iOS-like storyboard tool for Android project?

Tags: android, user-interface, uistoryboard

Do we, Android developers, have any tool like iOS developers have which can help us make story board of all activities and links between them?

Those who have seen iOS story board tool will know what I am talking about. It would be really cool as we would be able to visualise the UI logic.

PS. check my `storyboard` tag

Answer (score 17, accepted):

iOS [storyboards](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html) allow you to define the flow of your app without (almost) writing a single line of code using the Interface Builder.

I don't think there's similar tool for Android. You'll need to create the layouts separately and then glue them calling `startActivity` (or its relatives).

Comment: The tools look like Yahoo pipe. Interesting +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that tool well, but I think that you are looking for something like [fluidUI](http://www.fluidui.com)

There are dozens of similar tools and the best of them imho is still pen + paper.

Edit : [Jimu](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2013/03/could-jimu-be-missing-link-in-android.html) looks like it will be perfect for that role.

Comment: What if you have 30+ screens?! :)

Comment: Can fluidUI read android project and auto-draw screens or I have to do it manually (like in other mock-up tools)? I do not see such feature listed thou the project itself looks cool

Comment: I don't think that it can do that(I have to admit that I never had the need to do that). You are supposed to use this tool to plan how to make you UI, not the other way around :-).

If what you want to do is analyze the relationships between your Activities, you may want to have a look at the bundled hierarchyviewer
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am aware of that tool and it does not do what I need. in ios xcode tool you can create visual graph of all screens showing relations among each screen. very handy tool